# Regex to find all class names from .css file

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am working on a ticket for an open source project. There are over 800+ css files, and I need to get all the class names from all these files, and then check all the HTML files for these class names. The goal is to find which classes aren't being used anywhere in the project & delete them. So the 1st step is extracting all the class names properly.

The issue is I am having trouble constructing the correct Regex to get all the class names because some of the css files have class names that are not formatted properly, that are all on 1 line, jumbled like 1 big run-on sentence with minimal white spaces. So the Regex I created breaks on these occurrences and fails to extract the class names. I must create a more complex yet flexible Regex and I seek guidance.

Example of some of the formats:

```css
.class-Name-Here {
}

.class1,.class2,.class3 {
}

.class1 .class2 {
}
```

But then there are really messed up formats like this (real example):

```css
.toast-title{font-weight:700}.toast-message{word-wrap:break-word}.toast-message a,.toast-message label{color:#FFF}.toast-message a:hover{color:#CCC;text-decoration:none}.toast-close-button{position:relative;right:-.3em;top:-.3em;float:right;font-size:20px;font-weight:700;color:#FFF;-webkit-text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;opacity:.8}.toast-top-center,.toast-top-full-width{top:0;right:0;width:100%}.toast-close-button:focus,.toast-close-button:hover{color:#000;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;opacity:.4}button.toast-close-button{padding:0;cursor:pointer;background:0 0;border:0;-webkit-appearance:none}.toast-bottom-center{bottom:0;right:0;width:100%}.toast-bottom-full-width{bottom:0;right:0;width:100%}.toast-top-left{top:12px;left:12px}.toast-top-right{top:12px;right:12px}.toast-bottom-right{right:12px;bottom:12px}.toast-bottom-left{bottom:12px;left:12px}#toast-container{position:fixed;z-index:999999}#toast-container *{-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}#toast-container>div{position:relative;overflow:hidden;margin:0 0 6px;padding:15px 15px 15px 50px;width:300px;-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;background-position:15px center;background-repeat:no-repeat;-moz-box-shadow:0 0 12px #999;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 12px #999;box-shadow:0 0 12px #999;color:#FFF;opacity:.8}#toast-container>:hover{-moz-box-shadow:0 0 12px #000;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 12px #000;box-shadow:0 0 12px #000;opacity:1;cursor:pointer}#toast-container>.toast-info{background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,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)!important}#toast-container>.toast-error{background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,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)!important}#toast-container>.toast-success{background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAADsSURBVEhLY2AYBfQMgf///3P8+/evAIgvA/FsIF+BavYDDWMBGroaSMMBiE8VC7AZDrIFaMFnii3AZTjUgsUUWUDA8OdAH6iQbQEhw4HyGsPEcKBXBIC4ARhex4G4BsjmweU1soIFaGg/WtoFZRIZdEvIMhxkCCjXIVsATV6gFGACs4Rsw0EGgIIH3QJYJgHSARQZDrWAB+jawzgs+Q2UO49D7jnRSRGoEFRILcdmEMWGI0cm0JJ2QpYA1RDvcmzJEWhABhD/pqrL0S0CWuABKgnRki9lLseS7g2AlqwHWQSKH4oKLrILpRGhEQCw2LiRUIa4lwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)!important}#toast-container>.toast-warning{background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,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)!important}#toast-container.toast-bottom-center>div,#toast-container.toast-top-center>div{width:300px;margin:auto}#toast-container.toast-bottom-full-width>div,#toast-container.toast-top-full-width>div{width:96%;margin:auto}.toast{background-color:#030303}.toast-success{background-color:#51A351}.toast-error{background-color:#BD362F}.toast-info{background-color:#2F96B4}.toast-warning{background-color:#F89406}.toast-progress{position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0;height:4px;background-color:#000;opacity:.4}.toast{opacity:1!important}.toast.ng-enter{opacity:0!important;transition:opacity .3s linear}.toast.ng-enter.ng-enter-active{opacity:1!important}.toast.ng-leave{opacity:1;transition:opacity .3s linear}.toast.ng-leave.ng-leave-active{opacity:0!important}@media all and (max-width:240px){#toast-container>div{padding:8px 8px 8px 50px;width:11em}#toast-container .toast-close-button{right:-.2em;top:-.2em}}@media all and (min-width:241px) and (max-width:480px){#toast-container>div{padding:8px 8px 8px 50px;width:18em}#toast-container .toast-close-button{right:-.2em;top:-.2em}}@media all and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px){#toast-container>div{padding:15px 15px 15px 50px;width:25em}}/*!
```

I need to create a really flexible Regex that can get all these class names.

The issue is that it's getting quite complex and I'm trying to create something that has:

I've done some analysis on the class names and they follow these general rules:

1. start with . and can be chained several times:
   Ex: `.Interesting-Complex.Class-Name2.Specialty_Class {`
2. Uses `A-Z`, `a-z`, and *sometimes* `-` and `_` multiple times
3. Can end with either a newline, a comma, `{`, or `:`
4. Sometimes are preceded by `}`

My current expression is: `((?<=}))?\.(\w+(-+?)\w+)+?((?={)|(?=\s)|(?=,)|(?=:))`

But it does not work on simple cases such as:

```css
.glyphicon {
}
```

Because it thinks that the `-` is mandatory and so does not pick that up.
It is also failing on chained classes such as:
Ex: `.Interesting-Complex.Class-Name2.Specialty_Class {`

Comment: This is possibly beyond what you will be able to accomplish with just a regex, have you considered using a [css parser](https://pypi.org/project/css-parser/) and combing the AST for declarations?

Comment: Obligatory https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/978005

Comment: @JaredSmith I have not considered using a css parser, tbh I did not even know that existed. I will have to look into that. Because if a library for specifically css parsing exists, it makes more sense to use that.

Comment: @Phix Thank you for sharing - that made me laugh really hard. *HTML leaking from your eyes like liquid pain*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @JaredSmith, you should not use regex, but a full-fledged CSS parser. For example, [*tinycss2*](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/tinycss2/stable/):

```py
import tinycss2

def get_css_classes(string):
  # A list of QualifiedRules, AtRules and Comments
  rules = tinycss2.parse_stylesheet(string)
  
  for rule in rules:
    if rule.type != 'qualified-rule':
      continue
    
    # 'prelude' means the tokens preceding '{'
    # See https://doc.courtbouillon.org/tinycss2/stable/api_reference.html#tinycss2.ast.QualifiedRule
    prelude_tokens = rule.prelude
    
    for index, token in enumerate(prelude_tokens[1:], 1):
      previous_token = prelude_tokens[index - 1]
      
      if token.type == 'ident' and previous_token == '.':
        yield token.value
```

For the following content:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .class-name {
    display: none;
    & > #nested-css { caret-color: #e8403a }
  }
}

.class-Name-Here {
}
.class1,.class2,.class3 {
}

.class1 .class2 {
}.glyphicon {
}

.Interesting-Complex.Class-Name2.Specialty_Class {}
```

It outputs:

```py
[
  'class-Name-Here', 'class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class1', 'class2',
  'glyphicon', 'Interesting-Complex', 'Class-Name2', 'Specialty_Class'
]
```

As you can see, this function is very crude and does not handle at-rules correctly. However, it should provide a good baseline for your actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following pattern.

```
(?:(?<=[{},]\.)|(?<=^\.))[^{}/]+?(?=[{,\s])
```

- `(?:(?<=[{},]\.)|(?<=^\.))`, is preceded by a `.`, and subsequently, `{`, `}`, `,`, or the start of the line
- `[^{}/]+?`, any character except `{`, `}`, and `/`, one or more
- `(?=[{, ])`, is followed by `{`, `,`, or `\s`

Here is an example utilizing a *list comprehension*, with *[re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer)*.

```py
p = r'(?:(?<=[{},]\.)|(?<=^\.))[^{}/]+?(?=[{,\s])'
[print(x.group()) for x in re.finditer(p, s)]
```

Output

```
toast-title
toast-message
toast-message
toast-message
toast-message
toast-close-button
toast-top-center
toast-top-full-width
toast-close-button:focus
toast-close-button:hover
toast-bottom-center
toast-bottom-full-width
toast-top-left
toast-top-right
toast-bottom-right
toast-bottom-left
toast
toast-success
toast-error
toast-info
toast-warning
toast-progress
toast
toast.ng-enter
toast.ng-enter.ng-enter-active
toast.ng-leave
toast.ng-leave.ng-leave-active
```